# RemoteApp working with Azure Windows Server 2012

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, remoteapp

Hoping someone can shed some light on my RemoteApp/Azure dilemma

I have successfully setup RDS on Server 2012 VMs in Azure - session host, rdweb and connection broker, opted not to have a gateway as only running one session host.

Created an self-signed certificate in RDS tools in Server Manager and bound this to rdweb, named the cert remote.cloudapp.net. I also uploaded this to the cloud service for the VMs using Azure powershell.

So via an Azure VM on the domain in Azure I can connect to remoteapp and successfully run an application.

However when I connect externally via a browser on my standalone laptop I get the following error in the RDS Log:

> Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed to redirect the user
>   REMOTE\appuser.  Error: NULL

I have tried the fix of look for an Pool ID of NULL in the Windows Internal Database and I only have one pool ID which is the collection I created, so can't be that.

Also get this error returned when I try to run a remoteapp after successfully logging into the RDweb page:

> Remote Desktop Services cannot connect to the remote computer for one
>   of these reasons: Remote Access is not enabled to the server Remote
>   computer turned off Remote computer not available on the network

I am totally stumped, is there something I am missing that is so simple.

Comment: You connect via a Browser? Don't you think the problem is your browser if it works with rdp? Check at the port

Comment: I don't think its my Browser - I can access the RDWeb website its when I try to connect to a remoteapp - the RDP connection box opens I click connect and am waiting for the login box to appear and then the error occurs.

Comment: Angela Cataldp - I've got the same issue; if you open the "Boot Diagnostics" you can see that the machine is stuck at a window that is asking for "settings" input or to click "next."  Hopefully, someone can point you/us in the right direction on how to get past this screen.